# I killed my camel and now he won't come to me when I whistle. Can I fix this without buying a new one?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

I was doing a quest in Alexandria and was suddenly attacked by bandits. I dismounted my camel (the Wanderer), but because of the cleave damage of the sword I used, I accidentally killed him. I had no idea this was possible, but after I tried to whistle for him, he didn't come to me.

Is the wanderer dead for good? Will I have to buy a new camel? Or can I resurrect the poor animal in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was WAY too soon with making this question. A few seconds after posting this question, I whistled for my camel again, and this time he DID come for me. So he's not dead for good.